# Modify syntax of this function to exclude several arrays instead of one

Tags: php, arrays

I'm a newbie to PHP and don't know how to modify the syntax of this function so that it can be used to exclude several arrays instead of only one. This code automatically INSERTS every value that's input in a form without having to specify the fields and excludes one array (called 'submit'), and is a slightly modified version of code that I found at  http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2007/10/inserting-an-array-into-a-mysql-database-table/

I have several arrays which are being posted that I want to exclude from my INSERT function since they are either being processed and inserted separately or trigger where the user is redirected once the form is processed.

```
function mysql_insert_array($db, $data, $exclude = array()) { 
$fields = $values = array(); 
if( !is_array($exclude) ) $exclude = array($exclude); 
foreach( array_keys($data) as $key ) {
    if( !in_array($key, $exclude) ) {
        $fields[] = "`$key`";
        $values[] = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($data[$key]) . "'";
    }
} 
$fields = implode(",", $fields);
$values = implode(",", $values); 
if( mysql_query("INSERT INTO `$db` ($fields) VALUES ($values)") ) {       
} else {
    return array( "mysql_error" => mysql_error() );
} 
}
$result = mysql_insert_array("db", $_POST, "submit");
```

Comment: Please be aware: Tags aren't keywords.  Simply putting words in the tag list that are present in your question title isn't going to help properly categorize your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exclude argument could be an array of array:

```
    function mysql_insert_array($db, $data, $excludes = array()) { 
      $fields = $values = array(); 
      if( !is_array($excludes) ) $excludes = array($excludes); 

      foreach($excludes as $exclude ) {
        $data = array_diff_assoc($data, $exclude);
      } 

      foreach( array_keys($data) as $key ) {
        $fields[] = "`$key`";
        $values[] = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($data[$key]) . "'";
      }

      $fields = implode(",", $fields);
      $values = implode(",", $values); 
      if( !mysql_query("INSERT INTO `$db` ($fields) VALUES ($values)") ) {       
        return array( "mysql_error" => mysql_error() );
      }
    }
```

Then, you could use it like this :

```
$array1 = array('toto', 'titi', 'tata');
$array2 = array('submit', 'foo');

$parent_array = array ($array1, $array2);

$result = mysql_insert_array("db", $_POST, $parent_array);
```

Comment: How would I specify the names of the arrays? The original code is for an array called 'Submit', and is specified in the statement: $result = mysql_insert_array("db", $_POST, "submit");

Comment: no, the original code is not for an array called Submit, the original code just pass a string which is added in an array. If you want to specify multiple array, you have to add them in a parent array

Comment: This is incredibly helpful :-) Thank you @Nico!